# How to upload an image from gallery to supabase storage

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase, react-native-image-picker, supabase-js

I want users to be able to pick a profile picture from the gallery using the Image Picker from expo and upload it to supabase in a filename that is structured like this `userid.jpeg`. I then want to access this file and get its url to display the image when i need it. The issue is that a file is being uploaded to supabase but its either 0 bytes or doesn't contain anything. Could somebody please help me i am a beginner.

Here is my code for context:
Pick image from gallery code:

```
 const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: false,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 0.7,
        });
      
        if (!result.canceled) {
          // Access the selected asset from the assets array
          const selectedAsset = result.assets[0];
          setProfileImage(selectedAsset.uri);
        }
          };
```

Uploading to supabase storage code:

````
        try {
        console.log("Starting upload...");
          const sanitizedId = sanitizeFilename(userId); // Sanitize the user id
          const filename = `${sanitizedId}.jpeg`; // Assuming you want to save as jpeg
    
          // Convert the file URI to blob
          const blob = await fetch(imageUri).then((res) => res.blob());
          console.log("Uploading blob...");
          const { error } = await supabase
            .storage
            .from('profile-pictures')
            .upload(filename, blob, {
              cacheControl: '3600',
              contentType: 'image/jpeg', // Specify the content type
              upsert: false
            });
    
          if (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading profile picture:', error);
            return null;
          }
          console.log("Getting public URL...");
          const { data } = await supabase
            .storage
            .from('profile-pictures')
            .getPublicUrl(filename);
    
          console.log('Profile picture URL:', data);
          return data;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in uploadProfilePictureToSupabase:', error);
          return null;
        }
      };
      const sanitizeFilename = (filename) => {
        return filename.replace(/[^\w.-]/g, ''); // Replace invalid characters
      
      };```



I tried using blobs but i got even more confused.
````

Answer (score 2):

According to the Supabase [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload?example=upload-file-using-arraybuffer-from-base64-file-data)

"For React Native, using either Blob, File or FormData does not work as intended. Upload file using ArrayBuffer from base64 file data instead, see example below."

```js
import { decode } from 'base64-arraybuffer';

const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('public/avatar1.png', decode('base64FileData'), {
    contentType: 'image/png'
})
```

[base64-arraybuffer library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer)

To get the base64 string you use:

```js
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
   mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
   allowsEditing: false,
   aspect: [4, 3],
   quality: 0.7,
   base64: true, //Add this line
});
```